# HTML5 Application Guidelines Required

Tags: html

I am very new to HTML 5 rather dnt know much about HTML5 yet.
I want to create a HTML5 application which will represent data which will be accessed from a web service.

1. If I am using Local Storage will my data will be store in sqlite file? If yes where it gets saved ?
2. Do I have alternative way to save the data locally which I am accessing from web service?

I tried to use by doing xmlhttpRequest Object, it works fine in IE but not working in Mozilla and Chrome, below are my code snippets

```
 function webServiceCallWithParameters() {
try {
        alert("1");
        var xmlHttpReq;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        alert(xmlHttpReq);
            xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttpReq.open("POST", "http://localhost/EventWebService/Service.asmx/Add", false);
        xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttpReq.send("num1=12&num2=13");
        alert(xmlHttpReq.responseText);
    } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1.If I am using Local Storage will my data will be store in sqlite file?

That depends on how any given browser has implemented local storage, but why does it matter?  It makes no difference to your web app how it's stored.

> If yes where it gets saved ?

Again, that depends on the browser implementation, but again why does it matter?  It makes no difference to your web app where it's stored.

> 2.Do I have alternative way to save the data locally which I am accessing from web service?

You could use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB).

Comment: I will put my query in other words. I have a web service which will access data from SQL server, not I want to read this data and show it using HTML 5, how I can do that?

Comment: I have tried to call the web service and it's webmethod using XMLHTTPRequest. I have updated my post with code snippet. But It works well only in IE not in Mozilla and Chrome.I am getting a exception "Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101" - Requesting Cross- origin permission.

Comment: @sunshine Why are you trying to call a web service in a different domain? Have you set set [CORS headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)?

Comment: Currently the web service is on my local machine and where as the HTML5 page too, so how it will be get called from different domain ? I didnt get this concept ? I didnt set any CORS headers yet, can u please guide

Answer (score 0):

There are many offline technologies available in case of `HTML5`

They are

1. Web Storage,
2. Web SQL Database,
3. Indexed Database,
4. File Access

See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/ for in depth description about these storage techniques and comparison between them.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Advantages:

1. less code
2. more features like css animations
3. less usage of javascript
4. easy mobile UI conversion
5. easy integration with HTML or CSS frameworks and MVC

Disadvantages:

1. not support all browsers and all versions